# How to have sharper rise for ideal filter frequency response in matlab

Tags: analog, matlab

I am writing about analog filters in my blog and I decided to plot the frequency responses using matlab, representing the responses using step functions. But matlab uses heaviside function which does not rise from 0 to 1 instantaneously. Any help on how to plot accurate ideal frequency responses in matlab would be appreciated

matlab plots the heaviside like this:[image]

But I want something like this:
[image]

edit: added images for better clarification

Comment: The heaviside step function *does* rise instantaneously.

Comment: Texh Geek - Hi, At the moment, your post looks too much like an advert for your blog. To avoid your post potentially being treated as spam (meaning it could be edited or deleted) please [edit] your question *as soon as possible*, include *all* relevant details in the question itself, and remove the link to your blog. If some info is *needed* to be able to answer your question, it should be included in the question *here*, not in a blog. || You can add a link to your blog on your [profile page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/338120/texh-geek). Thanks.

Comment: Texh Geek - Hi, It seems you have gone offline. Looking at the link you gave, there was nothing at that general link which seemed specific to your question for me to copy into your question for you. Therefore, rather than deleting your post as [spam](/help/promotion), I've just deleted the link as it didn't actually support the text in the question. || I recommend adding examples of your attempts to use matlab, into your question. || As you are new here, please read the [tour] & [help] to see the main site rules and to see how Stack Exchange differs from typical internet forums. Thanks.

Comment: @Hearth See [Wolfram's discussion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html) as starters. If treated as a generalized function, Heaviside(0) returns the whole interval of [0,1], not some specific value. Treated piecewise, it is often given 1/2. So, technically, regardless of piecewise or generalized function it is *not* instantaneous. Heaviside(x) may be used as the derivative of a max(0,x) function and then these questions become important. When used to simply cut a function domain on the real axis, it's value at 0 isn't so relevant. But I'd cut some slack to the questioner.

Comment: @Hearth In MATLAB in particular, per the questioner, the Heaviside step function, H(x), returns 1/2 at x = 0. This is likely due to their idea of defining a modified version that is continuous: $$u_{_\alpha}\left(x\right)=\left\{\begin{align*}&1&&&&x\gt\frac{\alpha}2\\\\&\frac1{\alpha}\left(x+\frac{\alpha}2\right)&&&-\frac{\alpha}2\le\: &x\le\frac{\alpha}2\\\\&0&&&&x\lt -\frac{\alpha}2\end{align*}\right.$$ But that's a piecewise choice made by MATLAB and not a generalized Heaviside function. (Note that this is shown as \$u_{_\alpha}\left(x\right)\$ and not \$u\left(x\right)\$.)

Comment: @periblepsis: So choosing a small \$\alpha\$ would answer the OP's question? It woud allow a specified rise time and in the limit as \$\alpha\rightarrow0\$ be instantaneuous?

Comment: @RussellH I don't use MATLAB. I just read the manual, today. I am far more of a applied mathematician than an electronics specialist. I have a feel for generalized functions/distribution theory on \$\mathcal{R}^n\$. Given \$H_b\left(x\right)=\left\{\begin{align*}1\text{ if } x\gt b\\0\text{ if } x\lt b\end{align*}\right\}\$ then the function \$H_0\left(x\right)\$ is called the *Heaviside step function*. (Note that there's nothing said here when \$x=b\$. There is a reason for that.)

Comment: @RussellH More can be found [here](https://www.math.colostate.edu/~pauld/M545/6Distrib.pdf), for example, that fits closer to my view. My primary point is that the questioner here may be pointing out the practicalities applied by the MATLAB version, which seeks function continuity over mathematical rigor. One cannot really complain about that. It's practical and often done. But if the questioner then notices MATLAB's function as continuous and not instantaneous, then they are probably right about saying so. And telling them they are wrong may be a mistake.

Comment: @RussellH However, the questioner hasn't really said anything since posting the question. And they are the only one able to clarify their perspective. So I'm just guessing about it, frankly, seen more as a mathematician. Whether or not the questioner also meant to see it that way is for them to say. Not me. I'll have to wait and see.

Comment: @periblepsis Yes, I was talking about the practicalities of the matlab implementation. However, I was aiming for an idealised representation of the low pass filter, which can be represented as the difference of 2 step/unit functions. Matlab's version is continuous, but I wanted the instantaneous jump, hence the question

Comment: @TexhGeek Thanks for clarifying your question. It's quite clear, mathematically speaking, now. I'll +1 it now.